# CentOS 8: Modular dependency problems

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

Fresh install of CentOS 8 and I'm getting the following error when doing pretty much any dnf command. For example on yum remove I get:

```
# yum remove
Modular dependency problems:

 Problem 1: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBD-MySQL:4.046:8010020191114030811:073fa5fe-0.x86_64
 Problem 2: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(perl:5.26) needed by module perl-DBI:1.641:8010020191113222731:16b3ab4d-0.x86_64
 Problem 3: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides module(nginx) needed by module php:7.2:8010020191114034540:2430b045-0.x86_64
No packages marked for removal.
```

I'm not sure how this started, it might have been after I installed MariaDB. I've uninstalled it since, but the error persists. I need to resolve this error before moving on, so I dont mind remove any packages to do that.

I'm not really sure what it's referring to. I don't have perl-DBD perl-DBI or php installed on this system.

Answer (score 3):

As above but without the `perl-DBD-MySQL`:

```
yum module reset perl-DBD-SQLite perl-DBI php
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, though, that it is not clear which answer you are referring to, as the ordering depends on user settings. When referencing another post, add a link using the "share" URL below that post (and ideally indicate by which user it was created), so that readers may find it immediately. Also, since your answer _is_ almost the same as [that by @AdityaK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/587867/377345), you may want to edit it to explain what makes your approach different enough to merit an answer on its own.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else seem this, here's how I solved it. It seems to be an issue after installing MariaDB from the CentOS repositories.

```
 yum module reset perl-DBD-MySQL perl-DBD-SQLite perl-DBI  php
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what caused this on our server, but simply running the dnf/yum [module enable](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#module-command) command removed the modular dependency warning:

```
dnf module enable perl:5.26
```

This issue is also discussed here:

- [YUM (DNF) Possible Confusion CentOS 8](https://centosfaq.org/centos/yum-dnf-possible-confusion-centos-8/)
- [yum shows error "nothing provides module(perl:5.26) but perl-5.26 is available in the repository](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4678261)